# Repeat an ajax call to get most up to date data for table

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've got a fairly simple problem but I'm not sure where to start with it.

Im working with a fairly simple Laravel application currently, some things happening behind the scenes but currently I'm only interested in one page, which grabs a list of all the entries in a DB table made today, and lists them out.

The problem is, I want this to be dynamic, updating on the page each time a new row enters the database (A job runs a check every 5 minutes and fills a DB table in each time a condition is filled, google ads api.)

Currently the page only adds to the table when I refresh the page, I was told that "ajax" would help but having never used it, I've no idea where to start.

All I need is it to check the database every 30 seconds or so, and if it finds new rows, add them without refreshing the page.

Any advice or help you can give would be welcome.

Comment: You can make a loop where you call Ajax inside the loop every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setInterval function with AJAX here is the demo. I hope this could help.

```
setInterval(
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {_method: "GET"},
                    url:'/YourRoute',
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    success:function (output) {
                        $("#yourDataTable").append('Append to div')
                    },
                    error:function (data) {
                        var errorMessage = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    },

                });
            }, 300000);
```

Comment: This might work... so I'd need to set that .append to do whatever it is that adds my new rows?

Comment: you have to call the function via the ajax method and keep fetching the data and append to the existing table or div.